# How to integrate $\int\int (x+y)^2\sin(x^2-y^2)dxdy$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I need to integrate $\int\int (x+y)^2\sin(x^2-y^2)dxdy$ on the range $D$ which is given by a rectangle with the vertices: $(0,1),(0,2),(1,0),(2,0)$.

This is an illustration:

[image]

The suggested way to go about solving the integral is substitution method.

We can find the equations of the 4 lines that form the trapezoid:
$$
y+x=1\\
y+x=2\\
x=0\\
y=0
$$

Seems straightforward to choose $x+y=u$ and $x-y=v$. But while it's easy to do it for $u$ I don't see how to get values for $x-y$. I guess we could say that $x-y=-y$ but that will hold for any $y$ so we can't get a specific point.

**EDIT:**

Finally I arrived to the approach which converts the points from $xy$ coordinates to $uv$. What we need to do is essentially plug in the $(x,y)$ points into $u=x+y, v=x-y$ equations. So for example, for $(x=0,y=1)$ we have $u=0+1=1, v=0-1=-1$ so the equivalent point for $(x=0,y=1)$ in $uv$ coordinates will be $(1,-1)$. We can proceed with this approach to find the rest of the values:
[image]

This article was also very helpful: http://www.instructables.com/id/Change-of-Variables-of-Double-Integrals/

Comment: What do you get if you switch $x$ and $y$? What can you conclude from that?

Comment: Nice thought, @Pere, but OP did ask *how* to set up the integral, not what the value was. (Although I still prefer your answer. :) ).

Comment: You're right, I know. That's why I posted it as a comment ;)

Comment: @Pere Is it $x-y=1$ and $x-y=-2$? and the area is the $ABCD$ rhomboid as in this desmos graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/byqa7gqw2p?

Comment: @Yos I just meant that the symmetry of the problem can be exploited to greatly simplify the computation.

Comment: @Pere do you care elaborating on that?

Comment: @Yos Apply the transformation $F(x, y) = (y, x)$ to the integral. The Jacobian of this transformation is $-1$ (so its absolute value is $1$), $F$ maps $D$ to itself, and $f\circ F^{-1} = - f$. Applying the change of variables theorem, it follows that the integral is equal to its negative. So it must be $0$.

Comment: How did you get that the Jacobian is $-1$? If $\frac{1}{J}=\frac{\partial(u_x,u_y)}{\partial(v_x,v_y)}$ then $|J|=\frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: A typical constant-$u$ line, like $x + y = c$, will go from the upper left vertical line to the lower right horizontal line. For instance, $x + y = 5/4$ goes from 
$(0, 5/4)$ to $(5/4, 0)$. The first of these has $x - y = -5/4$; the second has $x-y = 5/4$. So when $u = 5/4$, the inner integral needs to go from $-5/4$ to $5/4$. Repeat this process for every possible value of $c$ from $1$ to $2$ to discover how to write the upper and lower limits for your inner integral in terms of the outer integral's integration variable, $u$.

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand. I don't understand the formal reasoning on why $x-y=2, x-y=-2$ are relevant for us and how we can conclude $v$ values from them

Comment: If we're in $uv$ plane then $u=1, u=2$ are on the $u$ axis. $x-y=2$ is just another line which crosses $(2,0)$ in $xy$ plane but so what?

Comment: Is it $x-y=1$ and $x-y=-2$? and the area is the $ABCD$ rhomboid as in this desmos graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/byqa7gqw2p?

Comment: I never said anything about $x-y = 2$ or $x-y = -2$, so I cannot understand what you're talking about. Try drawing the lines $u = 1, 1.5, 2$ on top of your graph; they should be diagonals. What are the $v$-limits on each of these? (Don't try to do this mechanically yet: just draw the picture and figure it out.)

Comment: Is $v=x-y$? I don't know what you mean by limits of $v$.

Comment: Are limits the intersection points between $y$, $x$ axes and $u$?

Comment: Is this the area now, the rectangle PQST https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0ocjg6jmuk? I'm sorry I'm asking these questions but I can't understand what I need to do from your answer

Comment: YOU were the one who wrote "Seems straightforward to choose $x+y=u$ and $x-y=v$." I was just using your notation. The rectangle you've drawn doesn't look right at all, but I haven't worked through the problem in detail. The limits are *determined* by the intersection of the segments $AC$ and $BD$ in your picture with each $u = $ constant line. But you need to find the $uv$-coordinates of the intersection points, not the $xy$ coordinates, which is why I changed $(x, y) = (0, 5/4)$ into $v = x - y = -5/4$, for example.

Comment: While the choice of $u=x+y, v=x-y$ is straightforward as is finding that $1 \le u \le 2$ finding the range of $x-y$ is not straightforward at all to me and I don't understand your hints/explanation at all. If you don't mind I'd rather delete the question and re-post it in hopes that someone will provide an exhaustive explanation. I'm not looking for answer only but I need to understand the logic which I can't from your answer unfortunately

Comment: Well, I've suggested you draw a picture, and you haven't done so. Doing so might help you understand, which is why I suggested it. When you do, you can add it to your question by clicking "edit" just beneath the question. So: please draw, atop your current pic: 1. The $v$ axis, i.e., the line on which $u = x+ y$ is zero. 2. The $u$-axis, i.e., the line on which $x - y$ is zero. 3. The line $u = 1$. 4. The line $u = 1.5$. 5. The line $u = 2$. For the last three, also show what part of the line you've drawn is within the region $ACBD$. Then identify the $uv$ coordinates of the lines' endpoints.

Comment: Also: you cannot delete a question that has a upvoted answer. Probably other folks have looked at this and said "Ah, John's given a decent start; let's see what happens..." (Often, when folks don't think this, they post their own answers quite soon.)

Comment: Believe I've been drawing pictures of this all day. Is this the right picture? http://imgur.com/a/4taTs if yes what can I conclude about $uv$ coordinates?

Comment: Add the picture to your question, and maybe I'll say something about it. If you know the $xy$ coordinates of a point, do you know how to find the $uv$ coordinates? Hint: you've got formulas for $u$ and $v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.